# CyberAgent/android-gpuimage: How to implement parallel filter pipeline?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, video-processing, gpuimage

Using GPUImage in iOS I can apply multiple filters like this:
[two parallel filter pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD2lY.png)

by code:

```
[videoCamera addTarget:filter1];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter2];
[filter1 addTarget:filter3];
[filter2 addTarget:filter3 atTextureLocation:1];
[filter3 addTarget:videoView];
```

However, when going to Android, I can not implement this filter pipelines using CyberAgent/android-gpuimage. Have anyone experienced with it? or give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

can´t you do something like?:

```
 mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection());
 mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter());
```